# If statement block is not executing at all

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, microsites

```
SET @activities = Replace(@activities,'[', '|')
SET @activities = Replace(@activities,']', '|')
SET @activities = Replace(@activities,'"', '')
SET @firstActivtiesRowSet = BuildRowsetFromString(@activities,"|")

SET @rowFirst = Row(@firstActivtiesRowSet, 2)
SET @activitiesGroup = Field(@rowFirst, 1)

SET @secondActivtiesRowSet = BuildRowsetFromString(@activitiesGroup,"{")
FOR @i = 1 TO Rowcount(@secondActivtiesRowSet) DO

    SET @rowSecond = Row(@secondActivtiesRowSet, @i)
    SET @singleActivity = Field(@rowSecond, 1)

    SET @thirdActivtiesRowSet = BuildRowsetFromString(@singleActivity,",")


    FOR @j = 1 TO Rowcount(@thirdActivtiesRowSet) DO

        SET @rowThird = Row(@thirdActivtiesRowSet, @j)
        SET @singleKeyValue = Field(@rowThird, 1)
    ]%%
                    %%=v(@singleKeyValue)=%%
                %%[
        SET @fourthActivtiesRowSet = BuildRowsetFromString(@singleKeyValue,":")
        SET @rc = ROWCOUNT(@fourthActivtiesRowSet)

        IF @rc > 1 THEN
            SET @rowKey = Row(@fourthActivtiesRowSet, 1)
            SET @rowValue = Row(@fourthActivtiesRowSet, 2)
            SET @key = Field(@rowKey, 1)
            SET @value = Field(@rowValue, 1)

                ]%%
                    %%=v(@key)=%% %%=v(@value)=%% <br/>
                %%[
            IF @key == "bu_id" THEN
                ]%%
                    <tr>
                %%[
            ELSEIF @key == "additional_info" THEN
                    ]%%
                    </tr>
                %%[
            ELSEIF @rc == 4 THEN
                SET @time1 = Row(@fourthActivtiesRowSet, 3)
                SET @time2 = Row(@fourthActivtiesRowSet, 4)
                SET @value = CONCAT(@value, Field(@time1, 1), Field(@time2, 1))
                ]%%
                    <td>%%=v(@value)=%%</td>
                %%[
            ELSEIF @rc == 2 THEN
                IF @key == 'bu_id' THEN
                    ]%%
                    I am a BU!!!!!
                %%[
                ENDIF
                ]%%
                    <td>%%=v(@value)=%%</td>
                %%[
            ENDIF
        ENDIF
    NEXT @j


NEXT @i
```

So that is the code I have for my current project. I am trying to parse json code using ampscript. I have done this once before with more success. Here is a copy of the json I am using:
[http://pages.email.bostonglobe.com/bgcenterstage?a=getSubActivity&mids={10790742}&o=j&e=tcTest201@fulcrumtech.net&days=30][1]
So basically the code that reads

```
IF @key == "bu_id" THEN
                ]%%
                    <tr>
                %%[
            ELSEIF @key == "additional_info" THEN
                    ]%%
                    </tr>
                %%[
```

it never executes. It is a basic if statement, and the first two parts of the if statement do not execute, even though the @key is clearly written properly to the screen on the few lines before this code block. Any advice to get this statement to read in ampScript would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you update your question with the expected output?  You're mixing plain text between table tags, so I'm not quite sure what you're expecting to see.

Comment: And why aren't you stripping CR and LF from your JSON object if you're going to build rowsets with new delimiters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think trailing whitespace is the issue.  If you use the [trim()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#Trim) function on the `@key` and `@value` variables the conditional will work fine.

```
%%[
var @activities
set @activities = httpget("http://pages.email.bostonglobe.com/bgcenterstage?a=getSubActivity&mids={10790742}&o=j&e=tcTest201@fulcrumtech.net&days=30")
set @activities = replace(replace(@activities,char(10),""),char(13),"")
SET @activities = Replace(@activities,'[', '|')
SET @activities = Replace(@activities,']', '|')
SET @activities = Replace(@activities,'"', '')
SET @firstActivtiesRowSet = BuildRowsetFromString(@activities,"|")

SET @rowFirst = Row(@firstActivtiesRowSet, 2)
SET @activitiesGroup = Field(@rowFirst, 1)

SET @secondActivtiesRowSet = BuildRowsetFromString(@activitiesGroup,"{")

FOR @i = 1 TO Rowcount(@secondActivtiesRowSet) DO

    SET @rowSecond = Row(@secondActivtiesRowSet, @i)
    SET @singleActivity = Field(@rowSecond, 1)

    SET @thirdActivtiesRowSet = BuildRowsetFromString(@singleActivity,",")


    FOR @j = 1 TO Rowcount(@thirdActivtiesRowSet) DO

        SET @rowThird = Row(@thirdActivtiesRowSet, @j)
        SET @singleKeyValue = Field(@rowThird, 1)

        output(concat("<br><br>@singleKeyValue: ", @singleKeyValue))

        SET @fourthActivtiesRowSet = BuildRowsetFromString(@singleKeyValue,":")
        SET @rc = ROWCOUNT(@fourthActivtiesRowSet)

        IF @rc > 1 THEN

            SET @rowKey = Row(@fourthActivtiesRowSet, 1)
            SET @rowValue = Row(@fourthActivtiesRowSet, 2)
            SET @key = Field(@rowKey, 1)
            SET @value = Field(@rowValue, 1)
            set @key = trim(@key)
            set @value = trim(@value)

            output(concat("<br>@key: ",@key," @value: ",@value))

            IF @key == "bu_id" THEN

                output(concat("<br>start row"))

            ELSEIF @key == "additional_info" THEN

                output(concat("<br>end row"))

            ELSEIF @rc == 4 THEN

                SET @time1 = Row(@fourthActivtiesRowSet, 3)
                SET @time2 = Row(@fourthActivtiesRowSet, 4)
                SET @value = CONCAT(@value, Field(@time1, 1), Field(@time2, 1))
                output(concat("<br>#1 @value: ",@value))

            ELSEIF @rc == 2 THEN

                IF @key == 'bu_id' THEN
                    output(concat("<br>I am a BU!!!!!"))
                ENDIF

                output(concat("<br>#2 @value:",@value))
            ENDIF
        ENDIF
    NEXT @j

NEXT @i
]%%
```

**Output:**

```
@singleKeyValue: 

@singleKeyValue: bu_id: 10790744
@key: bu_id @value: 10790744
start row

@singleKeyValue: send_date: 2015-12-01T00:00:00.000Z
@key: send_date @value: 2015-12-01T00
#1 @value: 2015-12-01T000000.000Z

@singleKeyValue: send_id: 34646393
@key: send_id @value: 34646393
#2 @value:34646393

@singleKeyValue: campaign_name: Today's Headlines
@key: campaign_name @value: Today's Headlines
#2 @value:Today's Headlines

@singleKeyValue: activity_type: Sent Email
@key: activity_type @value: Sent Email
#2 @value:Sent Email

@singleKeyValue: activity_date: 2015-12-01T10:07:00.000Z
@key: activity_date @value: 2015-12-01T10
#1 @value: 2015-12-01T100700.000Z

@singleKeyValue: additional_info: }
@key: additional_info @value: }
end row

@singleKeyValue: 

@singleKeyValue: bu_id: 10790744 
@key: bu_id @value: 10790744
start row

@singleKeyValue: send_date: 2015-12-01T00:00:00.000Z
@key: send_date @value: 2015-12-01T00
#1 @value: 2015-12-01T000000.000Z

@singleKeyValue: send_id: 34646393
@key: send_id @value: 34646393
#2 @value:34646393

@singleKeyValue: campaign_name: Today's Headlines
@key: campaign_name @value: Today's Headlines
#2 @value:Today's Headlines

@singleKeyValue: activity_type: Open
@key: activity_type @value: Open
#2 @value:Open

@singleKeyValue: activity_date: 2015-12-01T11:07:00.000Z
@key: activity_date @value: 2015-12-01T11
#1 @value: 2015-12-01T110700.000Z

@singleKeyValue: additional_info: }
@key: additional_info @value: }
end row

@singleKeyValue: 

@singleKeyValue: bu_id: 10790744
@key: bu_id @value: 10790744
start row

@singleKeyValue: send_date: 2015-12-01T00:00:00.000Z 
@key: send_date @value: 2015-12-01T00
#1 @value: 2015-12-01T000000.000Z

@singleKeyValue: send_id: 34646393
@key: send_id @value: 34646393
#2 @value:34646393

@singleKeyValue: campaign_name: Today's Headlines
@key: campaign_name @value: Today's Headlines
#2 @value:Today's Headlines

@singleKeyValue: activity_type: Click
@key: activity_type @value: Click
#2 @value:Click

@singleKeyValue: activity_date: 2015-12-01T11:09:00.000Z
@key: activity_date @value: 2015-12-01T11
#1 @value: 2015-12-01T110900.000Z

@singleKeyValue: additional_info: http://ThisIsLinkClicked.com }
@key: additional_info @value: http
end row

@singleKeyValue: 

@singleKeyValue: bu_id: 10790744
@key: bu_id @value: 10790744
start row

@singleKeyValue: send_date: 2015-12-01T00:00:00.000Z
@key: send_date @value: 2015-12-01T00
#1 @value: 2015-12-01T000000.000Z 

@singleKeyValue: send_id: 34646393
@key: send_id @value: 34646393
#2 @value:34646393

@singleKeyValue: campaign_name: Today's Headlines
@key: campaign_name @value: Today's Headlines
#2 @value:Today's Headlines

@singleKeyValue: activity_type: Sent Email
@key: activity_type @value: Sent Email
#2 @value:Sent Email

@singleKeyValue: activity_date: 2015-12-02T10:07:00.000Z
@key: activity_date @value: 2015-12-02T10
#1 @value: 2015-12-02T100700.000Z

@singleKeyValue: additional_info: }
@key: additional_info @value: }
end row

@singleKeyValue: 

@singleKeyValue: bu_id: 10790744
@key: bu_id @value: 10790744
start row

@singleKeyValue: send_date: 2015-12-01T00:00:00.000Z
@key: send_date @value: 2015-12-01T00
#1 @value: 2015-12-01T000000.000Z

@singleKeyValue: send_id: 34646393
@key: send_id @value: 34646393 
#2 @value:34646393

@singleKeyValue: campaign_name: Today's Headlines
@key: campaign_name @value: Today's Headlines
#2 @value:Today's Headlines

@singleKeyValue: activity_type: Open
@key: activity_type @value: Open
#2 @value:Open

@singleKeyValue: activity_date: 2015-12-03T11:07:00.000Z
@key: activity_date @value: 2015-12-03T11
#1 @value: 2015-12-03T110700.000Z

@singleKeyValue: additional_info: }
@key: additional_info @value: }
end row

@singleKeyValue: 

@singleKeyValue: bu_id: 10790744
@key: bu_id @value: 10790744
start row

@singleKeyValue: send_date: 2015-12-01T00:00:00.000Z
@key: send_date @value: 2015-12-01T00
#1 @value: 2015-12-01T000000.000Z

@singleKeyValue: send_id: 34646393
@key: send_id @value: 34646393
#2 @value:34646393

@singleKeyValue: campaign_name: Today's Headlines 
@key: campaign_name @value: Today's Headlines
#2 @value:Today's Headlines

@singleKeyValue: activity_type: Click
@key: activity_type @value: Click
#2 @value:Click

@singleKeyValue: activity_date: 2015-12-03T11:09:00.000Z
@key: activity_date @value: 2015-12-03T11
#1 @value: 2015-12-03T110900.000Z

@singleKeyValue: additional_info: http://ThisIsLinkClicked.com } 
@key: additional_info @value: http
```

Oh, and use the [output()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#Output) or [outputline()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#OutputLine) functions with [concat()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#Concat).  Sometimes it makes the code easier to follow, especially with a bunch of nested loops and conditionals.

Comment: I tried to upvote this, but my reputation is not 15 yet. Trim solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Glad the solution worked. Would you mind accepting this answer? It might help people experiencing a similar issue and will help getting your question noticed. For more information, take a look at our [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: I don't know how to accept it, I only have a reputation of 6, not 15.

Comment: You should just be able to click the checkmark under the up/down arrows on the left side of your question.  Don't think that requires any level of reputation.

Comment: Thanks. Hey it gave me two more points. Need 7 more now. Got any knowledge about this issue? I will give you more points. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103552/minutes-not-formatting-properly-in-ampscript