# Minutes not formatting properly in AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to format a date.

`2015-12-01T00:00:00.000Z`
Into 
`12/01/2015 12:00AM`

Now I have the following code to remove the Z and T and pass in a format that would work, but it looks like it is changing the minutes into hours, because it always put the minutes down as 12, when there is a 0 in the number.

`2015-12-01T11:09:00.000Z`
converts to
`12/01/2015 11:12AM`

Here is the code:

```
%%[
IF @key == "send_date" OR @key == "activity_date" THEN

    SET @time1 = Row(@fourthActivtiesRowSet, 3)
    SET @time2 = Row(@fourthActivtiesRowSet, 4)
    SET @value = CONCAT(@value, ":",Field(@time1, 1), ":", Field(@time2, 1))
    SET @separateDate = BuildRowsetFromString(@value,"T")
    SET @rowDate = Row(@separateDate, 1)
    SET @date = Field(@rowDate, 1)
    SET @rowTime = Row(@separateDate, 2)
    SET @time = Field(@rowTime, 1)
    SET @dateTime = CONCAT(@date, " ", @time)
    SET @separateDate = BuildRowsetFromString(@dateTime,"Z")
    SET @rowDate = Row(@separateDate, 1)
    SET @dateTime = Field(@rowDate, 1)
]%%
    <td>
        %%=Format(StringToDate(v(@dateTime)), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:MMtt")=%%<br>
        %%=v(@value)=%%
    </td>
%%[ endif ]%%
```

Please advise on how to get the minutes to use 60 and the hours to use 12, right now it looks like the minutes is formatting to 12. Also, please upvote this, I am not up to 15 reputation yet to vote people up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to convert the input string to a date first, but you will need to handle the timezone offset, since it's GMT (`Z`=> Zulu time).

```
%%[

 var @date, @formattedDate, @date2
 set @date = "2015-12-01T11:09:00.000Z"
 set @date2 = "2015-12-01T10:07:00.000Z"

 set @formattedDate = Format(dateadd(@date,"6","h"), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mmtt")
 set @formattedDate2 = Format(dateadd(@date2,"6","h"), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mmtt")

]%%
@date: %%=v(@date)=%%
<br>@date2: %%=v(@date2)=%%
<br>@formattedDate: %%=v(@formattedDate)=%%
<br>@formattedDate2: %%=v(@formattedDate2)=%%
```

**Output**

```
@date: 2015-12-01T11:09:00.000Z 
@date2: 2015-12-01T10:07:00.000Z 
@formattedDate: 12/01/2015 11:09AM 
@formattedDate2: 12/01/2015 10:07AM
```

Reference: [AMPScript Date and Time Formatting](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/#DateTimeFormatting)

**Update**: Added `@date2` and `@formattedDate2`

Comment: That still did not solve the minutes being seen as 12 base and not 60 base. It comes across a 0 and pushes it to a 12. 12/01/2015 04:12AM is what comes out of 2015-12-01T10:07:00.000Z
Format(StringToDate(v(@dateTime)), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:MMtt")=%%<br>%%=v(@dateTime)

Comment: I've updated my example.  Your string format is incorrect.  Give my example a try -- the whole `format()` line

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Thanks for the help. I checked it off. Thanks.